# Working Support Ticket Bot for Discord built with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is a working support ticket bot for discord using discord.py api. There is a slash command to launch the system which brings up a button to submit a ticket which when clicked creates a new text channel where only the ticket creator and the admins have access. also, upon creation of the ticket(channel) a notification is sent to a webhook and a notification popup is sent to the guild. the admins or the ticket creator at that time have the option to add or remove members from the channel(ticket) for inclusion in the conversation and when the action is over there is a button to close and/or create a downloadable transcript. it works as it is. i only wonder if it has any holes or areas for improvement or simply bad code practice. thanks.

```
import discord, os
from datetime import datetime
from discord import app_commands, utils, Webhook
from discord.ext import commands
import aiohttp

guild_id = 0
role_id = 1



class ticket_launcher(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        self.cooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 600, commands.BucketType.member)
    
    @discord.ui.button(label = "Create a Ticket", style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id = "ticket_button")
    async def ticket(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        interaction.message.author = interaction.user
        retry = self.cooldown.get_bucket(interaction.message).update_rate_limit()
        if retry: return await interaction.response.send_message(f"Slow down! Try again in {round(retry, 1)} seconds!", ephemeral = True)
        ticket = utils.get(interaction.guild.text_channels, name = f"ticket-for-{interaction.user.name.lower().replace(' ', '-')}-{interaction.user.discriminator}")
        if ticket is not None: await interaction.response.send_message(f"You already have a ticket open at {ticket.mention}!", ephemeral = True)
        else:
            if type(client.ticket_mod) is not discord.Role: 
                client.ticket_mod = interaction.guild.get_role(role_id)
            overwrites = {
                interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = False),
                interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
                interaction.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, send_messages = True, read_message_history = True), 
                client.ticket_mod: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
            }
            try: channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(name = f"ticket-for-{interaction.user.name}-{interaction.user.discriminator}", overwrites = overwrites, reason = f"Ticket for {interaction.user}")
            except: return await interaction.response.send_message("Ticket creation failed! Make sure I have `manage_channels` permissions!", ephemeral = True)
            await channel.send(f"{client.ticket_mod.mention}, {interaction.user.mention} created a ticket!", view = main())
                  
            
            await send_hook(interaction)
                        
            
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"I've opened a ticket for you at {channel.mention}!", ephemeral = True)

class confirm(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        
    @discord.ui.button(label = "Confirm", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id = "confirm")
    async def confirm_button(self, interaction, button):
        try: await interaction.channel.delete()
        except: await interaction.response.send_message("Channel deletion failed! Make sure I have `manage_channels` permissions!", ephemeral = True)

class main(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
    
    @discord.ui.button(label = "Close Ticket", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id = "close")
    async def close(self, interaction, button):
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Are you sure you want to close this ticket?", color = discord.Colour.blurple())
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed, view = confirm(), ephemeral = True)

    @discord.ui.button(label = "Transcript", style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id = "transcript")
    async def transcript(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        if os.path.exists(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md"):
            return await interaction.followup.send(f"A transcript is already being generated!", ephemeral = True)
        with open(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md", 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"# Transcript of {interaction.channel.name}:\n\n")
            async for message in interaction.channel.history(limit = None, oldest_first = True):
                created = datetime.strftime(message.created_at, "%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
                if message.edited_at:
                    edited = datetime.strftime(message.edited_at, "%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
                    f.write(f"{message.author} on {created}: {message.clean_content} (Edited at {edited})\n")
                else:
                    f.write(f"{message.author} on {created}: {message.clean_content}\n")
            generated = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
            f.write(f"\n*Generated at {generated} by {client.user}*\n*Date Formatting: MM/DD/YY*\n*Time Zone: UTC*")
        with open(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md", 'rb') as f:
            await interaction.followup.send(file = discord.File(f, f"{interaction.channel.name}.md"))
        os.remove(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md")
    
class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True
        super().__init__(intents = intents)
        self.synced = False
        self.added = False
        self.ticket_mod = 1

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id=0))
            self.synced = True
        if not self.added:
            self.add_view(ticket_launcher())
            self.add_view(main())
            self.added = True
        print(f"We have logged in as {self.user}.")

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)




async def send_hook(interaction):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/.../...", session=session)
        await webhook.send(f"I've opened a new ticket for {interaction.user.name}!", username="Ticket Bot")




@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'ticket', description='Launches the ticketing system')
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_guild = True)
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(3, 60, key = lambda i: (i.guild_id))
@app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def ticketing(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "If you need support, click the button below and create a ticket!", color = discord.Colour.blue())
    await interaction.channel.send(embed = embed, view = ticket_launcher())
    await interaction.response.send_message("Ticketing system launched!", ephemeral = True)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'close', description='Closes the ticket')
@app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def close(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if "ticket-for-" in interaction.channel.name:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Are you sure you want to close this ticket?", color = discord.Colour.blurple())
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed, view = confirm(), ephemeral = True)
    else: await interaction.response.send_message("This isn't a ticket!", ephemeral = True)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'add', description='Adds a user to the ticket')
@app_commands.describe(user = "The user you want to add to the ticket")
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_channels = True)
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(3, 20, key = lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
@app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def add(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member):
    if "ticket-for-" in interaction.channel.name:
        await interaction.channel.set_permissions(user, view_channel = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{user.mention} has been added to the ticket by {interaction.user.mention}!")
    else: await interaction.response.send_message("This isn't a ticket!", ephemeral = True)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'remove', description='Removes a user from the ticket')
@app_commands.describe(user = "The user you want to remove from the ticket")
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_channels = True)
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(3, 20, key = lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
@app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def remove(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member):
    if "ticket-for-" in interaction.channel.name:
        if type(client.ticket_mod) is not discord.Role: client.ticket_mod = interaction.guild.get_role(role_id)
        if client.ticket_mod not in interaction.user.roles:
            return await interaction.response.send_message("You aren't authorized to do this!", ephemeral = True)
        if client.ticket_mod not in user.roles:
            await interaction.channel.set_permissions(user, overwrite = None)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"{user.mention} has been removed from the ticket by {interaction.user.mention}!", ephemeral = True)
        else: await interaction.response.send_message(f"{user.mention} is a moderator!", ephemeral = True)
    else: await interaction.response.send_message("This isn't a ticket!", ephemeral = True)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'transcript', description='Generates a transcript for a ticket')
async def transcript(interaction: discord.Interaction): 
    if "ticket-for-" in interaction.channel.name:
        await interaction.response.defer()
        if os.path.exists(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md"):
            return await interaction.followup.send(f"A transcript is already being generated!", ephemeral = True)
        with open(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md", 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"# Transcript of {interaction.channel.name}:\n\n")
            async for message in interaction.channel.history(limit = None, oldest_first = True):
                created = datetime.strftime(message.created_at, "%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
                if message.edited_at:
                    edited = datetime.strftime(message.edited_at, "%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
                    f.write(f"{message.author} on {created}: {message.clean_content} (Edited at {edited})\n")
                else:
                    f.write(f"{message.author} on {created}: {message.clean_content}\n")
            generated = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
            f.write(f"\n*Generated at {generated} by {client.user}*\n*Date Formatting: MM/DD/YY*\n*Time Zone: UTC*")
        with open(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md", 'rb') as f:
            await interaction.followup.send(file = discord.File(f, f"{interaction.channel.name}.md"))
        os.remove(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md")
    else: await interaction.response.send_message("This isn't a ticket!", ephemeral = True)

@tree.context_menu(name = "Open a Ticket", guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id))
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_guild = True)
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(3, 20, key = lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
@app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def open_ticket_context_menu(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral = True)
    ticket = utils.get(interaction.guild.text_channels, name = f"ticket-for-{user.name.lower().replace(' ', '-')}-{user.discriminator}")
    if ticket is not None: await interaction.followup.send(f"{user.mention} already has a ticket open at {ticket.mention}!", ephemeral = True)
    else:
        if type(client.ticket_mod) is not discord.Role: 
            client.ticket_mod = interaction.guild.get_role(role_id)
        overwrites = {
            interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = False),
            user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
            interaction.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, send_messages = True, read_message_history = True), 
            client.ticket_mod: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
        }
        try: channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(name = f"ticket-for-{user.name}-{user.discriminator}", overwrites = overwrites, reason = f"Ticket for {user}, generated by {interaction.user}")
        except: return await interaction.followup.send("Ticket creation failed! Make sure I have `manage_channels` permissions!", ephemeral = True)
        await channel.send(f"{interaction.user.mention} created a ticket for {user.mention}!", view = main())   
        await interaction.followup.send(f"I've opened a ticket for {user.mention} at {channel.mention}!", ephemeral = True)

@tree.error
async def on_app_command_error(interaction: discord.Interaction, error: app_commands.AppCommandError):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        return await interaction.response.send_message(error, ephemeral = True)
    elif isinstance(error, app_commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        return await interaction.response.send_message(error, ephemeral = True)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred!", ephemeral = True)
        raise error

client.run("...-...")
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Things to note in regards to "bad practice code". While yours isn't necessarily "bad practice" it is definitely better practice to use cogs.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer and I don't use discord. What are cogs? While this isn't a bad answer, it could be better. Could you please expand the answer so that others can use it in learning.